# There's something wrong with tables in libgdx

Tags: java, android, image, libgdx

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img;
Stage stage;
@Override
public void create () {
    stage=new Stage();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    Image mg=new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
    Table table=new Table();
    table.add();
    table.add(mg);
    table.add();
    stage.addActor(table);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.end();
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
}}
```

Can anybody please tell me why it is that my image is not showing or what's wrong with this code? It works but I can't see my image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the size of the image, also most likely you'll need to specify the position and size of the table:

```
Image mg=new Image(new Texture("badlogic.jpg"));
Table table = new Table();
table.setSize(...;
table.setPosition(...);
table.add();
table.add(mg).size(...);
table.add();
stage.addActor(table);
```